# RegionFunction to clip ContourPlot3D results in unexpected shading

Tags: plotting, regions

I am attempting to use RegionFunction to trim an implicit surface drawn with ContourPlot3D to only show the portion inside of a sphere (instead of the bounding box from PlotRange).  However, when I attempt to do so, the region specified gets shaded in a little - which I do not want.  Here's a minimal example showing the issue,

```
ContourPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 - z^4 - 1 == 0, 
{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 25]
]
```

and a screenshot of it below.

[image: ContourPlot3DScreenshot]

The Mathematica documentation does not appear to show this shading of the region, and indeed when I copy/paste the example of a Plot3D with Regionfunction from the [documentation](http://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) it does not show up for me either.  I think I have had it working before for ContourPlot3D as well, but cannot find an old example of mine.  What is going on?

Comment: Does this happen on a fresh kernel?

Comment: Add the option `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`

Comment: @BobHanlon - this works! Thanks :)